# Does a PC cursed by Lycanthropy still retain racial bonuses to the same ability score?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, racial-traits, lycanthropy

This is mainly about a player who was bit by a Werebear recently.  He wants to embrace being a Werebear and he's a Human Variant Fighter (GWM Feat) with 17 Strength.  Being a Werebear he gains a Strength of 19, but he asked if his Variant Stats still apply.

Does a player character cursed by Lycanthropy still retain racial boosts to the same ability score?  i.e. Human Variant gives +1 Strength, so 20 Strength overall?

Comment: Werebear actually have incredible control over their curse, hence the Neutral Good alignment.  I let him know that full moons he might have trouble with that so the group has agreed that before the next full moon they'll restrain him to see what happens.

Other than that he was already really hairy-- so just a bit more hair in human form?  He's already made the group aware, even transformed to show them and he spends a lot of time meditating to help retain control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

They gain a strength of 19, and it is set to that number unless they increase it after the fact. It is similar to other items that buff ability scores, such as belts of giant strength.

MMp207 is where the Lycanthropy in player character rules are.

Comment: What about Ability Score Increases? Are ASI boosts to Strength lost? What about ones applied after contracting  lycanthropy? Could they use an ASI to increase their  strength to 20?

Comment: @divibisan That sounds like a new question.

Comment: @divibisan there is now a question for it https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160778/are-the-ability-scores-granted-by-lycanthropy-permanent